# Using jQuery With Sitecore

Tags: jquery, sitecore

I'm trying to get a jQuery slide show working on a web control that I've created. I can get the slide show to work in IE 9 with compatibility mode turned on, but I can't get it to work properly in Chrome or Firefox.

I'm not very experienced with jQuery, so I may be missing something obvious. I'm not sure if using Sitecore as the CMS has something to do with my problem or not.

This is some example code that I found on the web and have been playing around with. Can anyone help?

Thanks! 
crjunk

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var currentPosition = 0;
    var slideWidth = 500;
    var slides = $('.slide');
    var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
    var slideShowInterval;
    var speed = 3000;


    slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);

    slides.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder"></div>')

    slides.css({ 'float': 'left' });

    $('#slidesHolder').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);


    (function changePosition() {
        if (currentPosition == numberOfSlides - 1) {
            currentPosition = 0;
        } else {
            currentPosition++;
        }
        moveSlide();
    })(jQuery);


    (function moveSlide() {
        $('#slidesHolder')
              .animate({ 'marginLeft': slideWidth * (-currentPosition) });
    })(jQuery);

});
</script>


<div id="slideshow">
 <div id="slideshowWindow">
    <div class="slide">
             <img src="../../images/slider_1.jpg" />
             <div class="slideText">
                 <h2 class="slideTitle">Slide 1</h2>
                 <p class="slideDes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                 consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                 incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                 <p class="slideLink"><a href="#">click here</a></p>
             </div><!--/slideText-->
        </div><!--/slide-->
    <div class="slide">
         <img src="../../images/slider_2.jpg" />
                 <div class="slideText">
                 <h2 class="slideTitle">Slide 2</h2>
                 <p class="slideDes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                 consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                 incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                 <p class="slideLink"><a href="#">click here</a></p>
             </div><!--/slideText-->
    </div><!--/slide-->
    <div class="slide">
         <img src="../../images/slider_3.jpg" />
                 <div class="slideText">
                 <h2 class="slideTitle">Slide 3</h2>
                 <p class="slideDes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                 consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                 incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                 <p class="slideLink"><a href="#">click here</a></p>
             </div><!--/slideText-->
    </div><!--/slide-->
 </div><!--/slideshowWindow-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version of Sitecore you are using, there can be a

> [... conflict with Prototype.js that most of Page Editor, including
>   designer and debugger uses. It can be simply worked around by
>   overriding the $-function by calling "jQuery.noConflict()"](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2009/01/jquery-conflicts-with-pageeditor.html)

Once you get past this Sitecore nuance, the problem is your javascript/css code. Being you are admittedly not a jQuery guy I would look into leveraging a canned solution for a slideshow such as http://slidesjs.com

Comment: I am using  Sitecore 6.3.1 (rev. 110112). These are the changes I made. (Assuming I understand the articel corrctly). I added 
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); to the script, then I replaced all occurrences of $ with $j. The DIVs Slideshow and Slideshow window are now being rendered, however the SlidesHolder DIV is not.

Comment: Based on that Sitecore version, you are required to force No Conflict. Once you get past that it isn't a Sitecore issue. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! The example code that I was working with has some type of issue. Switching to a different slide show example code corrected the problem.

Comment: You can also wrap your entire function in the fully-qualified jQuery wrapper: `jQuery(function($){ // now you can use $ in here });`

Answer (score 6):

You should note that the Page Editor (in preview mode) injects a script tag for "jQuery.noconfict.js" which end with: window.$sc = jQuery.noConflict();

This not very good since it overwrites the window.jQuery variable which everyone is using when they write jQuery('.myclass')

jQuery standard functionality still works fine. 
BUT... any modules and jQuery extensions NOT LOADED BEFORE THE INJECTION will not work since they are loaded by a jQuery instance which is no longer the one referenced by "window.jQuery".

"jQuery.noconfict.js" is injected right under the body tag. This means that in PREVIEW MODE all references to jQuery in script tags anywhere in body will use the Sitecore noconflict instance with no modules loaded instead of the one you think!

In short: don't use the jQuery variable and don't use $ ... make your own jQuery variable in your own namespace

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that the $ is not necessary at all to use jQuery, it's just a shortcut.  If you replace all the $() instances with jQuery() it should work without conflict in Sitecore.  It's just the $ that prototype uses which is conflicting.  Also, Mark's comment about wrapping is also handy.

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easier wrap your code in an anonymous function and pass the jQuery variable in. This is probably more obvious if you’re writing some code others will use like a jQuery plugin, but could help save you down the line.

Adding the anonymous function and passing the jQuery variable in will prevent problems later with the $ variable.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Do some awesome stuff...
            });
        })(jQuery);

    </script>
```